# Hibernate pure sql: setter for one to one join class (entity/table)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, class, join

I have simular (but much longer) pure sql query:

```
    .createSQLQuery("
    SELECT a.title, ....., b.type_id, b.type_title, c.city_id, c.city_name
    FROM articles as a 
    INNER JOIN content_type as b ON a.type_id=b.type_id
    INNER JOIN city_list    as c ON a.city_id=c.city_id
    WHERE a.id=1")
    .addScalar("title")
    .....
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Article.class))
```

and some java code:

```
            @Table(name="articles")
    Class Article ... { 
    ...
            @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
            @OneToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="type_id")
    private ContentType type;
            @OneToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="city_id")
    private Сity city;
    ...
    }

            @Table(name="content_type")
    Class ContentType ... {
    ...
            @Column(name="type_id")
    private Long id;
    ...
    }

            @Table(name="city_list")
    Class City ... {
    ...
            @Column(name="city_id")
    private Long id;
    ...
    }
```

So, how i should mapped it after hibernate.createSQLQuery?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    .addJoin("b","type")
    .addJoin("c","city")
```

Thanks.

P.S. I need to save this query in pure sql cause "where" block in real query have certain logic that hibernate can't realize.

**UPD:** There is no problem to execute SQL query, promblem is how to map City and ContentType classes iside in Article class. That is, I get an NullPoinerException while trying access ContentType/City from result set (throw Article.getContentType()).

Comment: you can use @NativeSqlQuery(//Define your sql query here)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your query by using `createSqlQuery()` method or you can use HQL query using `createQuery()` method.

HQL conversion of your query is

```
SELECT a.title, b.type_id, b.type_title, c.city_id, c.city_name
FROM Article AS a 
INNER JOIN a.type AS b 
INNER JOIN a.city AS c
WHERE a.id = 1
```

hope this will solve your problem read about [HQL Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) 
also read about [HQL Vs Native SQL](http://premaseem.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/hibernate-vs-native-sql-execution-time-profoling/)